# Different instance methods generate the same object of inner class

Tags: python, oop, inner-classes

Here's a question about python. Apologies in advance if this is too basic.

Consider the following:

```
class H:
    pass


class D:
    def f(self):
        h = H()
        print("h:", h)


class C:
    def __init__(self):
        d1 = D()
        d2 = D()
        print("d1:", d1)
        print("d2:", d2)
        d1.f()
        d2.f()


c = C()
```

The output is the following:

```
d1: <__main__.D object at 0x1010fa6d8>
d2: <__main__.D object at 0x1010fa710>
h: <__main__.H object at 0x1010fa748>
h: <__main__.H object at 0x1010fa748>
```

Why is the `H` object being created the same, since it's being generated from two different instances of class `D`?

How can I create a different instance of `H` for each instance of `D`?

Comment: Not a Python expert, but they're probably not the same object, just in the same location. Since the lifetime of the two H objects don't overlap, it's fine to store them in the same location.

Comment: @AndrewLi That's exactly what is going on.

Comment: @AndrewLi  Thanks, that makes sense!